# Hide Div on Time of Day

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Javascript countdown timer, when it reaches 0, it shuts off and then resets the next day. Above it I have a 'We're Open' text. I want to hide that text and the rest of the div 'wereOpen' when the countdown reaches 0. The problem I am having trouble with is hiding the div 'wereOpen'.

[Website](http://www.securemyhome.com)

Javascript to hide div 'wereOpen'

```
!function ($) {
// get current time
// get current time
var d = new Date(), 
hours = d.getHours(),
mins = d.getMinutes();
day = d.getDay();   

// if day is mon-Fri and time is between 9am and 5:30pm
if(0 < dday < 7   
&& hours >= 21 
&& (hours < 24 || hours === 24 && mins <= 00)){

$('.wereOpen').hide(); 
};
}
```

Javascript for the countdown:

```
if (document.getElementById('countdown')) {
pad = function(n, len) { // leading 0's
    var s = n.toString();
    return (new Array( (len - s.length + 1) ).join('0')) + s;
};
function countDown() {
    var now = new Date();
    if ( (now.getDay() >= 1) && (now.getDay() <= 7) ) { // Monday to Sunday
        var target = 21; // 21:00hrs is the cut-off point
        if (now.getHours() < target) { // don't do anything if we're past the cut-off point
            var hrs = (target - 1) - now.getHours();
            if (hrs < 0) hrs = 0;
            var mins = 59 - now.getMinutes();
            if (mins < 0) mins = 0;
            var secs = 59 - now.getSeconds();
            if (secs < 0) secs = 0;
            var str = pad(hrs, 2) + ':' + pad(mins, 2) + '.<small>' + pad(secs, 2) + '</small>';
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = str;
        }
    }
}
var timerRunning = setInterval('countDown()', 1000);
}
```

Comment: What is the actual question? You say you've troubles, what kind of? You can't hide the div? A wrong div gets hidden? The div gets hidden at the wrong time? An error occurs...?

Comment: The condition `0 < dday < 7` doesn't make sense; other than `dday` being _undefined_, consider the following `0 < 2 < 2; // true` - it becomes `(0 < 2) < 2`, so `(true) < 2` and `+true` is `1` so we end up with `1 < 2; // true`. **Furthermore**, when is your function invoked? **A side note**, consider using UTC because websites can be viewed internationally where the time is different to your shop's local time.

Comment: I can't get the div 'wereOpen' to hide.

Comment: Also, It's okay to not be correct internationally since our business is only the U.S

Comment: If you take a careful look into your script, you'll notice, that there's nothing inside `countDown()`, which would hide the div. You have all that stuff in an anonymous function, which is even never called...

Comment: check this if it helps.. http://codewithlogic.wordpress.com/2014/02/17/running-javascript-at-specified-time-timed-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just playing around with a completely different way to solve "the problem" and I've ended up with the following, posting as it may be helpful for you

```
var open_times = {
        // day              hh  mm           hh  mm
        Monday:    { open: [ 9, 30], close: [17, 30]},
        Tuesday:   { open: [ 9, 30], close: [17, 30]},
        Wednesday: { open: [ 9, 30], close: [17, 30]},
        Thursday:  { open: [ 9, 30], close: [17, 30]},
        Friday:    { open: [ 9, 30], close: [17, 30]},
        Saturday:  { open: [ 0,  0], close: [ 0,  0]},
        Sunday:    { open: [ 0,  0], close: [ 0,  0]},
    },
    timezone = -(5*60 + 0);

function isOpen() {
    var d = new Date(),
        day, open, close;
    d.setUTCMinutes(d.getUTCMinutes() + timezone);
    day = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'][d.getUTCDay()];
    open = open_times[day].open[0] * 3600000 + open_times[day].open[1] * 60000,
    close = open_times[day].close[0] * 3600000 + open_times[day].close[1] * 60000;
    d = +d - (d.setUTCHours(0), d.setUTCMinutes(0), d.setUTCSeconds(0), d);
    if (open <= d && close > d)
        return {open: true, remain: close - d};
    else
        return {open: false, remain: 0};
}

function updateCountDown(ms) {
    var elm = document.getElementById('countdown'),
        ss = pad2(Math.floor(ms / 1000) % 60),
        mm = pad2(Math.floor(ms / 60000) % 60),
        hh = pad2(Math.floor(ms / 3600000) % 24);
    if (elm)
        elm.innerHTML = hh + ':' + mm + '.<small>' + ss + '</small>';
}

function pad2(x) {
    x = '' + x;
    if (x.length === 1) return '0' + x;
    if (x.length === 0) return '00';
    return x;
}

var timerRunning = setInterval(function () {
    var time = isOpen();
    if (time.open) {
        $('.wereOpen').show();
        updateCountDown(time.remain);
    } else
        $('.wereOpen').hide();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some incorrect variable names in your first piece of code, as well as some logic errors. According to your comment, I've adjusted the if statement:

```
if((day === 0 || day === 6)
   || (hours < 9 || (hours >= 17 && mins > 30)))
{
    $('.wereOpen').hide();
}
```

This statement will run if the day is saturday or sunday, or if the time is below 9am or above 5:30pm (local browser time).

Comment: How it will be run, if the function containing the `if` is never called?

Comment: @Teemu I was a little confused as to what exactly he was getting at in his question (same as you), so I just took a stab at something I saw that was incorrect.